# Manipular JSON con encabezados numericos

Tags: c#, json

Buenas tardes compañeros, estoy consultando un WS que me devuelve un json como el siguiente.

```
{
    "data": {
        "1130987": [
            1130987
        ],
        "1230988": [
            1230988
        ],
        "1331027": [
            1331027
        ],
        "1405538": [
            1405538
        ],
        "1508418": [
            1508418
        ],
        "1608432": [
            1608432
        ],
        "1708439": [
            1708439
        ],
        "32008440": [
            32008440
        ],
        "32008456": [
            32008456
        ],
        "1500002134": [
            1500010872
        ]
    },
    "range": {
        "total": 3182,
        "from": 1,
        "to": 10
    }
}
```

Los datos varían por lo que no puedo crear un modelo para poder transformar el json mi pregunta es. como puedo obtener los valores numéricos que vienen entre [].

Agradezco su tiempo. Saludos.

Comment: que es **Manuoular** ?

Comment: Manipular amigo, estoy tratando de cambiar el titulo pero no veo la opción de editar :/

Comment: Listo ya pude. Mil disculpas

Comment: debajo de la pregunta donde dice editar

Comment: Fredo. Disculpame que me comunique por aca pero soy nuevo y no se por donde comunicarme. Como resolviste este problema? El proveedor Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 no está registrado office 2016 no puedo solucionar. Gracias y perdon si no es este el medio de comunicacion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo si usas la clase correcta para mapear el json

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"{
                        'data': {
                            '1130987': [
                                1130987
                            ],
                            '1230988': [
                                1230988
                            ],
                            '1331027': [
                                1331027
                            ],
                            '1405538': [
                                1405538
                            ],
                            '1508418': [
                                1508418
                            ],
                            '1608432': [
                                1608432
                            ],
                            '1708439': [
                                1708439
                            ],
                            '32008440': [
                                32008440
                            ],
                            '32008456': [
                                32008456
                            ],
                            '1500002134': [
                                1500010872
                            ]
                        },
                        'range': {
                            'total': 3182,
                            'from': 1,
                            'to': 10
                        }
                    }";

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        foreach ( var item in data.DataItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value[0]);
        }
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public Dictionary<string,int[]> DataItems { get; set; }

    public Range range { get; set; }
}

public class Range
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int from { get; set; }
    public int to { get; set; }
}
```

La magia esta en definir la propiedad como `Dictionary<>`

```
 [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
 public Dictionary<string,int[]> DataItems { get; set; }
```

de esta forma los propiedades dinamicas mapean con este en donde el Value del diccionario sera un array numerico, tomando solo uno de estos

Comment: Wow Leandro, agradezco bastante la respuesta, había probado algo similar pero tu respuesta es perfecta, te agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que puedes usar esta estructura:

```
class Info
{
    public JObject Data { get; set; }
    public Range Range { get; set; }
}

class Range
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int From { get; set; }
    public int To { get; set; }
}
```

Esta seria la forma que te recomiendo para deserializar:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
 settings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Info>(jsonString, settings);

var items = value?.Data?.Values()
    .Select(x => x.First.Value<long>());

Console.WriteLine(items);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte :)